# Population Attributable Fraction adjusted for a variable

Tags: r, epidemiology, population-attributable-fraction

I am working in R tryign to estimate the population attributable fraction (PAF) for a binary outcome and 2 exposure variables that I had to coerce to become binary. I have used the "epi.2by2" function within epiR, but that gives me the simple calculation that I could have done easily by hand. Is there a way to adjust the PAF for an external fixed variable? Similar to how odds ratios can be adjusted. This is for a cohort count dataset, which is hard to find worked examples for (usually Case-Control).

Answer (score 2):

> "[R package] `attribrisk` Schenck, Atkinson, Crowson, and Therneau
> (2014) estimates PAFs in matched and unmatched case-control designs."

. . .

> "The new R package `graphPA` described here also estimates PAFs for
> cross sectional, case-control and cohort study designs under random
> samples."

source:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/graphPAF/vignettes/graphPAF_vignette.pdf